# Удалить текст из ссылок

Tags: html, jquery

Есть такой `HTML` код. Как удалить текст между тегами `<a></a>`. Т.е. именно цифры 1,2,3 ..

```
<ul class="bt_handles">
    <li class="">
        <a href="#0">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="#1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#2">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('.bt_handles a').html('');`

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните, где `2`. :-)

Comment: Ну, 2 случайно написала. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так: [`.text('');`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
$('a').text('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bt_handles">
    <li class="">
        <a href="#0">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="#1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#2">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сейчас